# UnAuthorized Exception occurs on connecting to Visual Studio Team Services from WIndows forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

Using the default code shown below from my windows application, I am expecting a IE popup for authentication to Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online):

```
TFS_ServerUri = https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(TFS_ServerUri));
tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

But I am getting "You are not authorized to access..."

Any idea how to get the pop-up.

Comment: When I enter the URL in the web browser, it gets re-directed to sign-in page where we initiate phone authentication. I want similar operation to happen from the windows forms. i.e. when I try to connect to the VSO URL, it pops-up web UI with sign-in page and initiate phone authentication. Once authentication is success, return to the widows application.  Do I need use a different API for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It would never give you a popup because 
tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
ensures that the user that has started the application is authenticated.
Besides you do not have a step to pass in the credentials, which you can add to the tfsteamprojectcollection constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
string vsuri = "https://yourvso.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection";
TfsClientCredentials tfcc = new TfsClientCredentials(false);
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(vsuri),tfcc);
tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
```